# org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of in android studio

Tags: android, json

When I try to retrieve a JSON object from an API, it causes an error. I'm using `JSONObjectRequest` to get the result.

This is my activity method:

```java
private void execute(final Context context) {
    String url = UrlManager.getUrl(context, R.string.signup_url);
    User user = User.getInstance();
    try {
        url += "&name=" + mFirstName + "&last=" + mLastName + "&mob=" + mMobile +
            "&email=" + mEmail +
            "&pass=" + UrlManager.prepareUrlPart(mPassword);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    final ProgressDialog pDialog;
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

    Response.Listener < JSONObject > listener = new Response.Listener < JSONObject > () {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject userObj = new JSONObject();
                userObj = response; //response.getJSONObject("UserInfo");
                userInfo = new UserInfo();
                userInfo.LoadItem(context, (JSONObject) userObj);
                String state = response.getString("State");
                if (state == "1") {
                    // Load user data from json and save them into local database
                    //  User user = User.getInstance();
                    // user.loadFromJSon(response);
                    /// user.saveUser();

                    onResult(true);
                } else {
                    onResult(false);
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };

    Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, listener, errorListener);
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

I've assured that my JSON is non-empty. Here's a sample JSON result:

```json
{"UserId":60,"UserName":"09111","Password":"123","Email":"m@m.com","Mobile":"09111111111","NationalId":"0000000000","FirstName":"mm","LastName":"mm","FatherName":"","Birthday":"1990/10/11","State":"1"}
```

This is the error in question:

```
org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new `JSONObject` ? Just use the argument `JSONObject response`.

Comment: i try this but not worked  @adm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private void execute(final Context context)
                {
                    String url = UrlManager.getUrl(context, R.string.signup_url);
                    User user = User.getInstance();
                    try {
                        url +=  "&name=" + mFirstName + "&last=" + mLastName + "&mob=" + mMobile  +
                                "&email=" + mEmail+
                                "&pass=" + UrlManager.prepareUrlPart(mPassword);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    final ProgressDialog pDialog;
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    pDialog.show();

                    Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                             JSONObject userObj = response;
 userInfo = new UserInfo();
     userInfo.LoadItem(context,
     userObj); 
    String state = userObj.getString("State");
     if (state .equals("1")) { 
    // Load user data from json and save them into local database 
    // User user = User.getInstance(); 
    // user.loadFromJSon(response);
     /// user.saveUser();
     onResult(true); 
    } else { 
    onResult(false); 
    }
      }
     catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Log.d("Error", e.getMessage());
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    };

                    Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    };

                    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,null, listener, errorListener);
                    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
                }
```

Comment: I tested two more mistakes were there :
u were using wrong variable and using == to compare strings in java

 try {
          JSONObject  userObj = new JSONObject(response);


        String state = userObj.getString("State");
        if (state .equals("1")) {
            // Load user data from json and save them into local database
            //  User user = User.getInstance();
            // user.loadFromJSon(response);
            /// user.saveUser();
Log.e("val",state);
        }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: when using JSONObject userObj = new JSONObject(response);  i get error cannot resolve constructor 'JSONObject (org.json.JSONOBJECT)'  @Er.-Pratik-Chatterjee

Comment: oh sorry i didnt saw response is a JsonObject and coded as a string
     u can assign:
     JSONObject  userObj = response;
or directly use response. will update the code i posted.

Comment: updated the code.copy n paste it

Comment: I changed this and Revealed the same error : org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 @Er.-Pratik-Chatterjee

Comment: will check in my studio n update.

Comment: can you post the stack trace once?

Comment: class com.android.volley.ParseError

Comment: it seems like there is an issue in the response/format of json from server as volley is showing parsing error. can u check if there is any new line or whitespace in beginning or end?
or can u send me the api request details so that i can check

Comment: there is a bug in api.. if data is different then response is given else empty string is returned instead of json object.

http://www.carnawash.ir/fa/Android/Signup?k=MILSA_ANDROID_CARNAWASH&a=andr&name=aaa&last=ddd&mob=09100000000&email=m@m.com&pass=123456

i mean there may be the code in api if the registration is successful then response is returned and i user is already there then nothing is returned. that time volley id getting empty response and throwing error at 0 length of string

Comment: Okay, I'll test this

Comment: thank you . problem solved. i love youuuu

Comment: Welcome milad. Can u kindly accept the answer if u dnt need any futher help on this?